# neo4j 3.2.5 WebSocket connection failure; centos7

Tags: browser, neo4j, websocket, bolt

> ERROR: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket readyState is: 3"

It works fine if I use HTTP but if I use https I get above error. I
tried on centos7, Alpine Linux on docker: same behavior. I also
tried https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/ : but it did not work for me.

neo4j.conf snippet:

```
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

Comment: Tried disabling HTTP Connector also.

Comment: Just figured out it was the CORS issue[Works fine if I disable CORS on web-browser]. Can anyone help me on,  how to allow accept anything in the web server for neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Docker to run neo4j application.
You are supposed to expose all the port used by neo4j.

```
docker run -d -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 -p 7473:7473 neo4j:latest
```